# Dataframe within a Dataframe? "do.call" gives error

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using [academictwitteR](https://github.com/cjbarrie/academictwitteR) to extract tweets using a search query with its `get_all_tweets` function. It is giving me the output as dataframe which has ***columns as dataframe***. Below is the sample dataset (df)

```
df <- structure(list(author_id = c("18166614", "590204178", "394175206", 
"2581787594", "835979767"), entities = structure(list(hashtags = list(
    structure(list(start = c(91L, 170L, 185L, 194L, 205L), end = c(100L, 
    184L, 193L, 203L, 216L), tag = c("phishing", "cybersecurity", 
    "Vishing", "SMiShing", "PhishProof")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    5L)), structure(list(start = c(72L, 151L, 166L, 175L, 186L
    ), end = c(81L, 165L, 174L, 184L, 197L), tag = c("phishing", 
    "cybersecurity", "Vishing", "SMiShing", "PhishProof")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    5L)), structure(list(start = 14L, end = 22L, tag = "Vishing"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 8L, tag = "Vishing"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    NULL), urls = list(structure(list(start = 146L, end = 169L, 
    url = "", expanded_url = "", 
    display_url = ""), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 127L, end = 150L, url = "", 
        expanded_url = " ", display_url = ""), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 103L, end = 126L, url = "", 
        expanded_url = "https://www.biocatch.com/resources/data-sheets/using-behavioural-biometrics-to-combat-vishing-and-app-fraud", 
        display_url = "biocatch.com/resources/data…"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = c(89L, 113L), end = c(112L, 136L), 
        url = c("", ""
        ),expanded_url = c("app", 
        "ht/photo/1"
        ), display_url = c("biocatch.com/resources/data…", "pic.twitter.com/LZcmikqlwA"
        ), media_key = c(NA, "3_1090735909463621632")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    NULL), annotations = list(structure(list(start = c(3L, 206L
), end = c(16L, 215L), probability = c(0.5826, 0.555), type = c("Other", 
"Other"), normalized_text = c("InspiredeLearn", "PhishProof")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(start = 187L, end = 196L, probability = 0.5316, 
        type = "Other", normalized_text = "PhishProof"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    NULL, NULL, NULL), mentions = list(NULL, NULL, structure(list(
    start = 3L, end = 12L, username = "BioCatch", id = "2581787594"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    NULL, NULL)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
)), source = c("IFTTT", "Hootsuite Inc.", "Twitter for iPhone", 
"HubSpot", "Twitter for iPhone"), id = c("1090739397803343872", 
"1090738965160824832", "1090736184614113281", "1090735911036506112", 
"1090735511914901504"), edit_history_tweet_ids = list("1090739397803343872", 
    "1090738965160824832", "1090736184614113281", "1090735911036506112", 
    "1090735511914901504"), created_at = c("2019-01-30T22:31:52.000Z", 
"2019-01-30T22:30:08.000Z", "2019-01-30T22:19:05.000Z", "2019-01-30T22:18:00.000Z", 
"2019-01-30T22:16:25.000Z"), possibly_sensitive = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), lang = c("en", "en", "en", "en", "en"), 
    public_metrics = structure(list(retweet_count = c(0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L), reply_count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), like_count = c(0L,7L, 0L, 2L, 0L), quote_count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L)), text = c("RT InspiredeLearn: If 2017 was the year of ransomware, 2018 was the year of the phish. And #phishing attacks are only growing more sophisticated.  #cybersecurity #Vishing #SMiShing  #PhishProof", 
    "If 2017 was the year of ransomware, 2018 was the year of the phish. And #phishing attacks are only growing more sophisticated.  #cybersecurity #Vishing #SMiShing  #PhishProof", 
    "RT @BioCatch: #Vishing scams are on the rise around the globe. Here's how banks can combat the threat. ", 
    "#Vishing scams are on the rise around the globe. Here's how banks can combat the threat.", 
    "Man we gotta get a grip on these “Vishing” calls I get everyday all day"
    ), conversation_id = c("1090739397803343872", "1090738965160824832", 
    "1090736184614113281", "1090735911036506112", "1090735511914901504"
    ), referenced_tweets = list(NULL, NULL, structure(list(type = "retweeted", 
        id = "1090735911036506112"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        NULL, NULL), attachments = structure(list(media_keys = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, "3_1090735909463621632", NULL)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L)), in_reply_to_user_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), geo = structure(list(
        place_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

When I run the command `do.call(data.frame, df)`, to convert the "column dataframes" to normal columns, it gives me the following error :

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: The dput is giving an error. can you check it

Comment: can You describe what is the goal?

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have updated the code. Please check now. Apologies for the error.

Comment: @KonradP , a few columns are saved as **dataframe** inside the dataframe. I want to convert them into normal columns.

Comment: and from "internal" dataframe do YOu want to extract certain values? I'm not sure how You want to "flatted" that dataframe.

Comment: is it possible to convert that "internal" dataframe to the columns like rest of them? For instance, if an internal dataframe has three variables (columns) inside, I want them to be added as columns to the master dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your `df` is nor a regular `data.frame` but an object of class `tbl_df` (see also [this explanation](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html)).

You can use `as.data.frame(df)`, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444413/11611246) to a similar question.
Some columns will still contain structures such as lists. If the output is not what you desired, you might want to explore the structure of `df` in order to write custom code for shaping the output as you need.

This answer explains how to change your output to class `data.frame` without producing the error. From your question, it is not clear what exactly you want to do with the result, though. It might be possible to do further analyses without this kind of conversion. Similarly, it is possible that storing the object as `data.frame` still does not suffice to run the code you intend to run. In such a case, you need to be clear about how the final `data.frame` has to be structured.

Comment: It is still giving the same output. I think the problem is because of the un-equal number of rows. For example ```entities$hashtags``` has three columns, but with different lengths, is there any way I can add NA where the values do not exist?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this error with the sample code. I simply get a ```data.frame``` as output...

Comment: Apparently, ```entities$hashtags``` is a list containing lists. Of course, you can edit those lists to make their numbers of rows match. However, this would require you to look into ```df``` and find out how it should be structured. E.g., you can access each object as ```df$entities$hashtags[[1]]``` and assign it some new list.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on this. For me, the ideal case would've been to just unnest the columns in those lists in the main dataframe.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how the urls and annotations should be matched with the hashtags. Do you even need all the columns? It seems in some columns, there can be lists with variable length. How you would organise your data highly depends on how you are planning to use it in subsequent steps.